# Vuex fails to call module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

When I try to call the module, I get the error **[vuex] unknown action type: signUp**
that doesn't work either, what's the problem? `this.$store.dispatch('auth/signUp', this.form)`

Method

```
methods:{
  signUp() {
    this.$store.dispatch('signUp', this.form)
  }
}
```

Store

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import auth from './modules/auth'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default function createStore() {
  return new Vuex.Store({
      state() {
          return {}
      },
      mutations: {},
      actions: {},
      modules:{
        auth,
      }
  })
}
```

Module (in src/store/modules/auth.js)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default function createStore() {
  return new Vuex.Store({
     state() {
        return {}
     },
     mutations: {},
     actions: {
       signUp({commit, getters}, data) {
         debugger
       },
     },
  })
}
```

Comment: A module shouldn't contain `Vuex.Store` and `Vue.use(Vuex)` at all

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `import Vuex from 'vuex'` in your store AND your module. This can cause problems like your module wont be recocnised, because your store already initialized.

Instead you should configure your `Vuex` store this way:

**Store**

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";
import auth from './modules/auth';
export default createStore({
  modules: {
    auth
  },
});
```

**Module**

```
  const state = {
    user
  };
  const getters = {
     getUserState: (state) => state.user
  };
  const actions = {
    signUp({commit}, data) {
      commit('signUpSuccess', data);
    },
  };
  const mutations = {
    signUpSuccess(state, user) {
      state.user = user;
    },
  }
  export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations,
  };
```